# MySQL queries getting slower with time

Tags: performance, optimization, mariadb

I have a table with around 900k entries. Around 600k of those get updated every 5 minutes. (using `REPLACE INTO`)

```sql
CREATE TABLE `servers` (
  `ipport` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `port` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip_as_int` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `version` text NOT NULL,
  `protocol` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `online_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `max_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `favicon` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_seen` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cracked` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `joined_on` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ipport`),
  KEY `ip_as_int_idx` (`ip_as_int`),
  KEY `last_seen_idx` (`last_seen`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

If I restart MariaDB (`systemctl restart mariadb`) the queries take around 3 seconds. The more time passes, the slower the queries get. (This morning I saw one that took 2 minutes!!!)

Server specs:
8 GB RAM
6 vCPU cores
8 GB swap memory

Variable dump:
https://pastebin.com/raw/5aXTxRV1

I am wondering why the queries are getting slower with time.

Queries are always similar to this (any of the columns can be used in the WHERE statement though):

```sql
SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(120000) */ * 
FROM servers AS s 
WHERE (protocol = 762) 
AND (s.last_seen > 1687177923) 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: What queries are performed? Are the columns that have indexes changed often too? If so, do you regenerate indexes?

Comment: So as 3 seconds is quite a long time, we really need to know WHICH query(s) you are talking about

Comment: @AdrianKokot I use REPLACE INTO, no idea if it regenerates all indexes

Comment: @RiggsFolly  
Queries are always similar to this: 

SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(120000) */ * FROM servers AS s WHERE (protocol = 762) AND (s.last_seen > 1687177923)  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100;

Comment: Would be useful to have that sort of information IN THE QUESTION

Comment: Consider adding indexes on `protocol` and `last_seen`

Comment: Btw, you have mariadb and not mysql. No, the two are not the same.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I hope you mean a single index on (protocol, last_seen)

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not image) output of `explain SELECT...rest of your query`.  also showing the REPLACE INTOs you are doing would be helpful.  are the replaces done individually over time or in bulk once every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

I would START with a compound index on both querying criteria.

```
table    index on
servers  ( protocol, last_seen )
```

Get rid of the max_execution_time.

Also, edit the post and show a little more specific of the actual queries and columns returned vs what appears to be concatenation of the query and c# style commenting.